# Apache server returns 200 response

Tags: php, html, apache

I got 2 different centos server(same vers. 6.7) and I have installed apache 2.2.15 for both servers. Problem is I can connect to my website at test1 server but I can't connect to my website at test2 server. Here is wget results for both servers. Is there any idea how to solve this problem?

```
[root@test1 ~]# wget localhost
--2015-11-18 14:01:45--  http://localhost/
Resolving localhost... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|::1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /login/mainpage/ [following]
--2015-11-18 14:01:45--  http://localhost/login/mainpage/
Reusing existing connection to localhost:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 7987 (7.8K) [text/html]
Saving to: “index.html”

100%[======================================>] 7,987       --.-K/s   in 0s

2015-11-18 14:01:46 (396 MB/s) - “index.html” saved [7987/7987]



[root@test2 /]# wget localhost
--2015-11-18 14:10:47--  http://localhost/
Resolving localhost... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|::1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4 [text/html]
Saving to: “index.html”

100%[======================================>] 4           --.-K/s   in 0s

2015-11-18 14:11:17 (666 KB/s) - “index.html” saved [4/4]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the connection works in both cases.

In both cases, you end up with a 200 reponse code and the file `index.html`.

The only difference is that in the first test case, your webserver does a 302 redirect from `http://localhost` to `http://localhost/login/mainpage`. And from there it returns `index.html`.

This is probably something that is set up in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Problem is both server has same php and .htaccess files. test1 server returns my website's index.html file but test2 server returns blank index.html file.

Comment: @hellzone, different `.conf` or `virtualhost` files ?